# HTTPClient - Capture a list of all Redirects

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is it possible to capture the full redirect history from a URL using HttpClient?

Say for example we have URL-A which redirects to URL-B which finally sends us to URL-C, is there a way to capture what URLs A, B and C were?

The most obvious option is to manually look for the location tag in the header, and stop when we reach a HTTP 200. This isnt a simple process as we would need to look for circular redirects etc etc...

Now I'm assuming the something along the lines of:

```
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(); 
    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(httpget, context);
    //.....
    for(URI u :  ((RedirectLocations)context.getAttribute(DefaultRedirectStrategy.REDIRECT_LOCATIONS)).getAll()){
                System.out.println(u);
    }
```

will work for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpClient supports custom [`RedirectHandler`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html). You can override the default implementation ([`DefaultRedirectHandler`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRedirectHandler.html)) to capture all the redirects.

```
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://google.com");
HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();


hc.setRedirectHandler(new DefaultRedirectHandler() {
    @Override
    public URI getLocationURI(HttpResponse response,
                              HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {

        //Capture the Location header here
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(response.getHeaders("Location")));

        return super.getLocationURI(response,context);
    }
});

HttpResponse response = hc.execute(httpget, context);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Does this mean the above method I have used in the question will not do what I want and I should be implemening my own redirect handler. We really dont need to do anything else than just get a list of all the redirects...

Comment: I reused something I had done. I couldn't get the proper dependencies of some class you refer. I would say simply test it. Google is an example of your use case. (google.com -> www.google.com -> www.google.?) or do a quick test server.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of testing with Google. Testing the above approach, it seems to work ok, but maybe its safer (and more flexible) to go with your approach.

Comment: Looks like `hc.setRedirectHandler` has been deprecated in 4.1.2... Any idea of what this process should be now?

Comment: Your first approach is probably better. It's shorter also.

Comment: @NightWolf As javadoc [from handler says](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html), use [`RedirectStrategy`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/RedirectStrategy.html).

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectHandler` is deprecated as of 4.1
`RedirectStrategy` is to be used.

we can override 2 methods `isRedirected` and `getRedirect`
In your case you can get all redirects by:

```
final HttpClientContext clientContext = 
        HttpClientContext.adapt(context);
RedirectLocations redirectLocations = (RedirectLocations)
    clientContext.getAttribute(
        HttpClientContext.REDIRECT_LOCATIONS
    );
```

You can add this code in `getRedirect`. This can also find this code in `getLocationURI` method of `DefaultRedirectStrategy` class.