# How to get a list of all redirected URLs using HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Is there anything like this from Java: [HTTPClient - Capture a list of all Redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860188/httpclient-capture-a-list-of-all-redirects)

for C# HttpClient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static string GetRedirectedUrls(string url)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(url);
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            url = response.GetResponseHeader("Location");
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```